# How do I fix a 404 in cache and blank Google results?

Tags: seo, google-search

I have a `static html` (using `gatsby-js`) site I'm hosting on Github Pages. I've added it to my Google Search Console, and the Fetch As Google renders it correctly (besides a few formatting issues):
[image: fetch as google screenshot] 
I've added it to the index several times after successful Fetch As Google renders.

However, when I search `site:example.com`, I get results I can't quite figure out:

[image: google results with incorrect title and blank description]

Even more strange, the `cache` returns my `404.html` page:

[image]

Strange because:

1. My `index.html`, afaik, has never thrown a `404` in the live version
2. I updated my `404` body text earlier today, and the `cached` version reflected the update (despite the `cached` version snapshot timestamp remaining unchanged)

The `meta description` and `title` of my page are present, both in the live site and the `cached` version.

So, how do I convince Google to show the `meta description` and `title`, and how might I fix the `404` in the `cached` version?

Comment: *So, how do I convince Google to show...* Wait. Be patient grasshopper! Search engines are ***NOT*** real-time.

Comment: What is strange about the `site:` search?  There is one ad (for Google Webmaster Tools) and the home page for your site.   The only thing that is odd is that "landing page" as opposed to your site title.   I assume that used to be the title.  Google takes a week or two to update sometimes.

Comment: thanks all--and I assumed it was a matter of time, but #2 in the OP explains my confusion.  I pushed an update today that added some body text (specifically, the `Oh NO!`)to my `404.html`, and the `cached` version updated almost instantly.  so, I thought there was some piece in the process I was missing.  really, the whole caching of my `404.html` instead of my `index.html` is the bigger concern--but I'm glad to hear none of this is so out of the ordinary.

Comment: You can always use the Fetch as Google and Submit to Index options in the Google Search Console for the pages you are concerned about. Still, this takes 1-2 days for the regular googlebot to come by and make the fetch official and update the index properly. You can continue to use Fetch as Google as many times as you need to trouble shoot issues before using Submit to Index. We have all done this. It will take time of course. However, Google is fairly fast and updates it's index rather rapidly considering the size of the web. Cheers!!